# A very detailed book for calculus 1-3.

Tags: calculus, reference-request, self-learning

Is there a very good book covering the **whole** calculus in detail, explaining **all topics in calculus 1-3** for self-learning? I'm in geometry I, so I will start calculus in two years, and finish in five years. But I don't care, I'm way ahead of everyone in my school and I already know calculus 1 and half of calculus 2. I just need to cover it again in **very good detail** because all that I know about it is unstable as there are no very good books that I can find nor very good tutorials online.

Comment: If you've seen calculus 1, why not just try out elementary analysis? Ken Ross's book is very friendly, and if you've seen induction, is probably accessible to you. If you're looking specifically for a calculus text, I like Zorich's book. The two volumes cover everything you're looking for, and are rigorous.

Comment: *Calculus*  by Tom Apostol (two volumes) is entirely comprehensive and rigorous.

Comment: @AlfredYerger does it cover how to solve derivatives/integrals, methods, or is it just theory?

Comment: @KKZiomek Zorich's book goes through a solid amount of theory and applications. It is aimed at the serious student of mathematics that is capable, but has never seen calculus before. It can be a little terse at times, as he often writes things formally. It covers everything you would find in a "basic analysis" course, but also applications in computation and the sciences. Over the two volumes, it includes multivariable calculus, and a plethora of other interesting and advanced topics.

Comment: If Zorich's text seems too advanced, or rather, if you're looking to be introduced to calculus int the way taught by many US high schools and colleges, try Thomas' Calculus. It's an undergraduate level texts with solid exposition. Easily digestible. It will set you up with the major theorems and machinery of calculus, including vector based applications. It's not a substitute for a book on analysis. The fact that you mention Calc 1-3 makes me think this book may suit you better than other options.

Comment: A very standard textbook is [Stewart's Calculus](http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-7th-James-Stewart/dp/0538497815).  I don't necessarily recommend it, but you should at least be aware of it.

Comment: Just on a side note, if you really like math, you may learn something like *real analysis* or *mathematical analysis* instead of *calculus*. Also, I would recommend Spivak's *Calculus*, which is better than most standard textbooks, though it doesn't seem to cover everything in calculus 1-3 (correct me if I'm wrong).